# How to Call Code Content from a Separate file and embed to the current file

Tags: javascript, html, ads

How can I implement this? I would like to call the code content of a txt file or HTML file and embed its content to the current file using a call-code-script or something.

adcodes.txt ---[call-script]--> display adcode content to current web page that has this 'script'

The reason I would like to do this is that. I have a 100 page static HTML website. And I would like to edit its ad codes, it hard for me to one by one edit the 100 pages. Sure, I can just mass edit 'find and replace' but in the future ill get into this problem again and this is the best idea I have.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What exactly the content of the file is and how you want to integrate it isn't clear, but you'd do something along the lines of:

```
fetch('/adcodes.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(responseText => {
    // do something with the raw text
    // document.body.appendChild( < element generated from responseText > );
  });
```

Comment: on the adcode file i have my adsense code for example. this method is like iframe but i dont want to use iframe.